# Notifications going to junk mail

Tags: cognito-forms

We are set with a form and a notification to our email address; although, each time it goes to the Junk Mail rather than the Inbox.

Is there something we are missing to do?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

You would need to add a rule to your email client or add notifications@cogntioforms.com to a whitelist so that the emails are not sent to junk.

If you are on the Team plan, you can set up a verified email domain to send emails via your domain. To do this you would need to contact us via our [Support Request](https://www.cognitoforms.com/supportrequest/).